# How to generate an install4j script from a installer?

Tags: install4j

I have an installer created by using Install4j. The problem is the script which was used for making this build is not available.I cannot recreate the script as the person who made the script is not available anymore. Is there any way I can generate the script from installer or installation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the installation, you can look at the file

.install4j/i4jparams.conf

It will give you clues about the configured screens, actions and form components. All scripts that are entered in the IDE, however, are compiled to class files and cannot be recovered.